# Trying to understand undefined value in JS console log

Tags: javascript, function, null

I've just taken my first steps into learning Javascript.

I'd like to us console log to find the children of my playToggle button but I'm getting
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener'). Please help me learn what I am doing wrong, I was under the impression that I had given playToggle a value.

```
const playToggle = document.getElementById('music- 
player');
 function changeIcon(){
     console.log(playToggle.children);
 }
 
 playToggle.addEventListener('click', changeIcon);
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
   <span id="music-player">some text</span>
     <i id="playBtn" class="fa-solid fa-circle-play"></i>
     <i id="pauseBtn" class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause"></i>
 </span>
 </div>
```

Comment: One of these conditions happened, There is no element that has an id equal to `playBtn` or you execute the script before rendering the `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the script tag placed correctly and no typo with id it should just work fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Show Children</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
      <span id="music-player">some text
        <i id="playBtn" class="fa-solid fa-circle-play"></i>
        <i id="pauseBtn" class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <script>
      const playToggle = document.getElementById('music-player');
        function changeIcon(){
        console.log(playToggle.children);
       }
      playToggle.addEventListener('click', changeIcon);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I have other code on the page that is working fine, and copy pasted the ID direct from the HTML to make sure of no mistakes. I just keep getting this error uncaught typeError, Now I've renamed the element Id names im getting undefined

Comment: Please update your question to include the entire file. Thanks.

Comment: Try placing your script tag ( javascript code) just before the end of the body <body> tag as in the example above. @Mina mentioned in the comment section that you might be executing the script rendering the DOM.

Comment: Strangest thing, my script tag is exactly where yours is. As both yourself and @Mina said, I made sure the ID's matched up. temporarily removed all irrelivant working code from the document so that i cold focus on the issue at hand. I'm just not able to get the output

Comment: I have updated it with your code. @Nisha is correct. In your code, the span tag is closed without wrapping the two icon <I> tag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    const playToggle = document.getElementById('music-player');
        
        function changeIcon() {
            console.log(playToggle.children);
        }

        playToggle.addEventListener('click', changeIcon);
```

```html
    <div class="theme-switch-wrapper">
        <span id="music-player">some text
        <i id="playBtn" class="fa-solid fa-circle-play"></i>
        <i id="pauseBtn" class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't comment on your post that's why I am writing here. The problem is span tag you closed span tag already after some text  so span has no child that's why it's not giving you children element.

Comment: How embarrassing! Thank you for the extra pair of eyes @Nisha. Long story short I did my own thing on a guid I was following, changed a few things and removed the extra span (side note, function still wasnt working before span removal.) the 'ammended snippet was posted'.  I've now removed the extra span altogether and it works fine.